# Render link in twig with 'entity:node/n' as uri in array

Tags: theming, 9

With the module "[config pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_pages)" I've set some variables global to render in templates.
In mytheme.theme I've added a function:

```
function mytheme_preprocess(array &$variables, $hook)
{
    $myConfigPage = \Drupal\config_pages\Entity\ConfigPages::config('config_name');
    $variables['my_settings'] = $myConfigPage->toArray();
}
```

In the config_pages I've created a link field.
I would like to render them, but I get below output.
How can I render the link in Twig?

```
  ^ array:3 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        "uri" => "entity:node/186"
        "title" => "Title 3"
        "options" => []
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        "uri" => "entity:node/189"
        "title" => "Title 1"
        "options" => []
      ]
      2 => array:3 [▼
        "uri" => "entity:node/195"
        "title" => "Title 2"
        "options" => []
      ]
    ]
```

Twig:

```
  {{ dd(my_settings.field_links) }}
  {% for link in my_settings.field_links %}
    <div class="field__item">
      {{ dd(link) }}
      {{ link.uri|render }}
      {{ link.title }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

None of above are working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render a link with [core's link function](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/functions-in-twig-templates#s-linktext-uri-attributes):

> This helper function accepts as first parameter the text and as second parameter the uri
>
> Examples:
>
> `{{ link(item.title, item.uri, { 'class':['foo', 'bar', 'baz']} ) }}`

In your case, this might look like:

```
{% for link_item in my_settings.field_links %}
  <div class="field__item">
    {{ link(link_item['title'], link_item['uri']) }}
    // or
    {{ link("My link text", "entity:node/123") }}
    // or
    {{ link("My link text", "internal:/some/internal/path") }}
    // or
    {{ link("My link text", "route:my.module.route_name") }}
    // or
    {{ link("My link text", "https://drupal.stackexchange.com/") }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, and preferably imo, you can just render the field from the config_page entity (as with any content entity).

For example, in your preprocess:

```
// Load your config page.
$my_config_page = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('config_pages')
  ->load('my_config_page_identifier');
// Build the render array for my links per the config page's `default` view mode.
$vars['my_links'] = $my_config_page->field_links->view('default');
```

Then, in twig:

```
{{ my_links }}
```

Comment: Thanks. So far I understand, but I have "entity:node/123" as array variable. So in Twig I need to use the function 'split'. I was wondering if there isn't a better solution.... I don't like to use to much logic in twig...

Comment: Yes there is. See my answer

Comment: What do you mean you need to use the function split? You can pass `entity:node/123` straight to the link function, e.g. `{{ link('My link text', 'entity:node/123') }}`

Comment: I was confused about the drupal_url() function, but indeed the core link function is what I need. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Also the update for the preprocess function is better. Config pages should have to update their documentation to use above.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for link in my_settings.field_links %}
    <div class="field__item">
      {{ link.uri|render }} => {{ link.url|render }} or {{ link.0.url|render }}
      {{ link.title }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

use **url** instead **uri** as mentioned above